How can I export all the rows rather than the currently displayed rows while using Data Tables export buttons and Server-side processing
I'm currently experiencing a challenge where my DataTable export buttons only exports the first 10 rows or currently visible rows instead of exporting all the Data or filtered data using the search bar. In other words it only exports the data in the first page of the DataTable.
Below what i have tried but still in vain:
        var table = $('#dt_payment_records').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('fees_management.payment_records.index') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'student.admission_no', name: 'student.admission_no'},
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        if (data.student.middle_name !== null) {
                            return data.student.first_name + " " + data.student.middle_name + " " + data.student.last_name;
                        } else {
                            return data.student.first_name + " " + data.student.last_name;
                        }
                    },
                    name: 'student_id',
                },
                {data: 'year', name: 'year'},
                {data: 'term', name: 'term'},
                {data: 'class.class_name', name: 'class_id'},
                { 
                    data: 'total_amount', 
                    name: 'total_amount',
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '')
                },
                { 
                    data: 'amount_paid', 
                    name: 'amount_paid',
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '')
                },
                { 
                    data: 'balance', 
                    name: 'balance',
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '')
                }
            ],
            dom: 'Bfrtip', // Include Buttons extension
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Copy',
                    className: 'btn btn-default',
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i> Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-default',
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF',
                    className: 'btn btn-default',
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print',
                    className: 'btn btn-default',
                }
            ]
        });

My Expectation is to export all the data or data in selection but only exporting the data on the first page of the DataTable.
Please note that while I'm not using server side processing, these buttons work just fine but since I'm processing large quantities of data i opted for server-side and now buttons are not working normally.

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

"buttons are not working normally" - No, the buttons are working correctly. I think you may have misunderstood how server-side processing is supposed to work. It is designed to only send one page of data at a time to DataTables - so DataTables can only export that one page of data. See the final FAQ in the Server-side processing FAQ section ("How can I export the whole table...?").

Does this answer your question? Get all data from Buttons extension (Excel).

See also Mimic the ( Show All ) link in datatables.net

I got the solution and i thought i would share it here:
Create this function within the .ready function;
  function newexportaction(e, dt, button, config) {
            var self = this;
            var oldStart = dt.settings()[0]._iDisplayStart;
            dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
                // Just this once, load all data from the server...
                data.start = 0;
                //data.length = 2147483647;
                data.length = dt.page.info().recordsTotal;
                dt.one('preDraw', function (e, settings) {
                    // Call the original action function
                    if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-copy') >= 0) {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.copyHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                    } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-excel') >= 0) {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                    } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-csv') >= 0) {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                    } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-pdf') >= 0) {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                    } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-print') >= 0) {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.print.action(e, dt, button, config);
                    }
                    dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
                        // DataTables thinks the first item displayed is index 0, but we're not drawing that.
                        // Set the property to what it was before exporting.
                        settings._iDisplayStart = oldStart;
                        data.start = oldStart;
                    });
                    // Reload the grid with the original page. Otherwise, API functions like table.cell(this) don't work properly.
                    setTimeout(dt.ajax.reload, 0);
                    // Prevent rendering of the full data to the DOM
                    return false;
                });
            });
            // Requery the server with the new one-time export settings
            dt.ajax.reload();
        };

and below is how the function is implemented is implemented;
dom: 'Bfrtip', // Include Buttons extension
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Copy',
                    className: 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i> Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF',
                    className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':not(.no-print)' 
                    }, // Exclude columns with the class 'no-print'
                   /*  orientation: 'landscape', // Set orientation to landscape
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL', // Optionally set the page size */
                    "action": newexportaction
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print',
                    className: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                }
            ]

With the above, now i can export all the data or data in selection without any hustle.
Thank you
